# Permission denied when trying to run PX4 roslaunch file

Tags: ros, px4, ros-melodic, roslaunch, permissions

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I'm trying to run PX4 multi_uav_mavros_sitl.launch file it throws permission denial errors and kills the processes like this:

```
[rospack] Unable to create temporary cache file /home/kris/.ros/.rospack_cache.nJAzB8: Permission denied
[uav0/sitl_0-3] process has died [pid 5203, exit code 255, cmd /home/kris/Pobrane/src/Firmware/build/px4_sitl_default/bin/px4 /home/kris/Pobrane/src/Firmware/ROMFS/px4fmu_common -s etc/init.d-posix/rcS -i 0 -w sitl_iris_0 -d __name:=sitl_0 __log:=/home/kris/.ROS_log/4da30ac2-15d2-11ea-bd56-080027229f95/uav0-sitl_0-3.log].
log file: /home/kris/.ROS_log/4da30ac2-15d2-11ea-bd56-080027229f95/uav0-sitl_0-3*.log
```

**my system:**

- ROS Melodic (supplied with PX4 stack)
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS x64 (kernel: 5.0.0-36-generic)

ROS enviroment variables:

```
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/melodic/etc/ros
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_VERSION=1
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=2
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/kris/catkin_ws/src/mavlink:/home/kris/catkin_ws/src/mavros/libmavconn:/home/kris/catkin_ws/src/mavros/mavros_msgs:/home/kris/catkin_ws/src/mavros/mavros:/home/kris/catkin_ws/src/mavros/mavros_extras:/home/kris/catkin_ws/src/mavros/test_mavros:/opt/ros/melodic/share
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/kris/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=melodic
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339065/permission-denied-when-trying-to-run-px4-roslaunch-file/) by [kris_1313](https://answers.ros.org/users/49957/kris_1313/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please show us the output of `ls -al $HOME/.ros`.

It's (very) likely that you've run `roslaunch` with `sudo` at some point in the past, which causes problems with access permissions for the `$HOME/.ros` directory.

---

Edit:

> ```
> drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 lis 23 19:43 .
> ```

as you can see from this, your `$HOME/.ros` is owned by `root`. That is why you receive permissions errors.

This should fix it:

```
sudo chown $USER: -R $HOME/.ros
```

This is one of the reasons never to run `roslaunch` (or `rosrun`) with `sudo` or as the `root` user.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kris_1313](https://answers.ros.org/users/49957/kris_1313/) on 2019-12-04**:
Here it is:

```
razem 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 lis 23 19:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 27 kris kris 4096 gru  4 15:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 lis 23 19:43 rosdep
```

edit: it worked like damn charm :)